# How to get list of payment methods/shipping method and assign it to a order (suitescript)

Tags: netsuite

I'm working with creating salesorder in netsuite using suitescript but I can't find any document about "payment method", so how can I get a payment method such as VISA card and assign to the order? (I think it's required a payment method id but I didn't find payment method in supported suitescript records).

[update]
Here is my code:

```
var order = nlapiCreateRecord("salesorder");
// set some field value
// order.setFieldValue(....)
```

Now I want get payment method and shipping method id to set to order:

```
order.setFieldValue("shipmethod", shippingmethodId);
order.setFieldValue("paymentmethod", paymentmethodId);
```

I already have payment method name "Test Payment Method" and shipping method "Test Shipping Method". How can I get their id using their name?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: @arulmr I updated question and added more detail

Answer (score 3):

**For Payment Methods:**

To get a list of the payment methods and their respective IDs available in your NetSuite account, you should navigate to Setup > Accounting > Accounting Lists. You will see a Type filter on the bottom of the page. Select Payment Method in there and you'll be able to see the different payment methods available for you.

**For Shipping Methods:**

Navigate to Lists > Accounting > Shipping Items.

Edit:

Actually you don't need to. Use `nlobjRecord.setFieldText` instead of `setFieldValue` i.e. `order.setFieldText('VISA')`

Comment: Actually you don't need to. Use nlobjRecord.setFieldText instead of setFieldValue i.e. order.setFieldText('VISA')

Answer (score -1):

You can use hard-coded values instead of getting the values dynamically.

Comment: I'm working with sync order to netsuite, so I can't use hard coded value.

Comment: To get the internal ids of Such fields what I usually do is get the values from console. Below are the steps

1- Open a new SO form
2- Set the Shipping method and payment method values
3- Open browser console (In most of the browsers it can be opened using Press F 12)
4- Execute nlapiGetFieldValue('shipmethod');
5- This will show the id of your selected ship method

Comment: the income order from another system, it doesn't know about netsuite shipping method internal id, it just has shipping method name.

Comment: @HoangLan just get all the ids from netsuite using the method described in my previous reply. Make an array of id and names in the importing script. Update the import process to convert the shipping name to internal id using this array .

Comment: really? is there anyway to make a search function instead?